# Embedding python in C++: Assigning C++ and python variables

Tags: python, embedding

I'm writing a small program (the one below) that embeds python in a C++ code.

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()     
{

    int x;
    Py_Initialize();

    const char* pythonScript = "print 'Start'"
    PyRun_SimpleString(pythonScript);

    /*
    assign a python variable 'n' to 'x' i.e n=x
    */

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0; 

}
```

My requirement here is that i assign the python variable 'n' the value of C++ variable 'x'.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at: http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html
You could also look into boost::python which makes it very easy...
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fragment should work (untested):

```
PyObject *main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__"); // borrowed
if (main == NULL)
    error();
PyObject *globals = PyModule_GetDict(main); // borrowed
PyObject *value = PyInt_FromLong(x);
if (value == NULL)
   error();
if (PyDict_SetItemString(globals, "n", value) < 0)
   error();
Py_DECREF(value);
```