# Passing variables to an embedded Python script from C++

Tags: python, c++

I need to run a Python script from c++, but I need also to pass it some variables. It can't be a function with parameters, because there are hundreds of variables, so the syntax would become too messy.
I will post a simple example, analogue to my case.
This is the Python script:

script.py

```
c = 10 * 5 + a
print(c)
```

And this is the calling code:

```
#include "Python.h"

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    
    PyObject *pName = PyUnicode_FromString("script");
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);;
    
    // Add something to set the cariable "a" in the script
    
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Could you help with the code to add to set the variable "a" in the script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding python in C++: Assigning C++ and python variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631018/embedding-python-in-c-assigning-c-and-python-variables)

Comment: Hi @mugiseyebrows, this answer is doing the opposite: it is assigning to a c++ variable the value of a variable in the Python script. Instead I need to assign the value of a c++ variable to the script, before it is executed.

Comment: If the contents of your script are as you say, then wouldn't the code already be executed at `import` time? I think you want [`PyRun_FileExFlags`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_FileExFlags) instead with a custom `globals` dictionary.

Comment: @Botje, I think your comment makes sense. Can you help with the example code so I can test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
Py_Initialize();
    
PyObject *locals = PyDict_New();
PyObject *globals = PyDict_New();

PyDict_SetItemString(locals, "a", PyLong_FromLong(123));
PyDict_SetItemString(locals, "b", PyLong_FromLong(9));

PyRun_FileExFlags(fopen("script.py", "r"), "script.py", Py_file_input, globals, locals, 1, NULL);

Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: Thanks @Botje, your solution is working, I added this line `PyObject* val = PyDict_GetItemString(locals, "c");` and `val` has the correct value. The only unexpected issue is that the console is not printing the value of `c` as from the command in the last line of the Python script. Is it possible to get that output in the console?

Comment: The print shows up for me...